# Performance with a large number of multiple output files in Hadoop

Tags: performance, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm using a custom output format that outputs a new sequence file per mapper per key, so you end up with something like this..

**Input**

```
Key1     Value
Key2     Value
Key1     Value
```

**Files**

```
/path/to/output/Key1/part-00000
/path/to/output/Key2/part-00000
```

I've noticed a huge performance hit, it usually takes around 10 minutes to simply map the input data, however after two hours the mappers weren't even half way complete. Though they were outputting rows. I expect the number of unique keys to be around half the number of input rows, around 200,000.

Has anyone ever done anything like this, or could suggest anything that might help the performance? I'd like to keep this key-splitting process within hadoop of possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your files would on average contain 2 rows? Why would you want to split your output into tons of tiny files? That would kill perfromance of the Hadoop cluster. The best perfromance you can get when you have about as many files as many reducers your cluster would support and when those files are about the same size.

Comment: I want to have an output file for each type of data I have, for example it could be access logs, and i'd like to have access data for each ip address as a separate file to use as input to something non-hadoop related.

Comment: If you are dealing with 200K or 400K rows, I believe you can get better perfromance on a standalone computer than on a Hadoop cluster.

Comment: Well, this is as an example, in production we'd be outputting 8-15 million different file locations. I've just started seeing performance issues at even 200,000, so its almost certainly not going to cope with any number larger than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you should revisit your design. I don't believe HDFS scales well beyound 10M files.  I suggest to read more on Hadoop, HDFS and Map/Reduce. A good place to start would be http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2009/02/the-small-files-problem/.

Good luck!

**EDIT 8/26:** Based on the @David Gruzman's comment, I looked deeper into the issue. Indeed the penalty for storing a large number of the small files is only for the NameNode. There is no additional space penalty to the data nodes. I removed the incorrect part of my answer.

Comment: I second this, Hadoop does not do well with a large volume of small files. You may be able to circumvent this limitation by concatenating all your files when they are imported to HDFS, then having your MR job write out to a smaller number of files. You could then Sqoop this output to a relational DB for non-Hadoop access, or use something like Hive or HBase to query directly into HDFS.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, i've read that article and was just a little hopefully I could squeeze this part of our data processing through hadoop, though its clearly not designed for this. Thanks again!

Comment: There is no space penalty for small files. Data node store only data we indeed have. The only hit is NameNode memory footprint

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like making output to some Key-Value store might help a lot. 
For example HBASE might suit Your need since it is optimized for big number of writes, and you will reuse part of Your hadoop infrastructure. 
There is existing output format to write right to HBase: http://hbase.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableOutputFormat.html